# Uncaught TypeError: CanvasSpliner is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [this repo](https://github.com/jonathanlurie/canvasSpliner) on a project since it's implementation would allow me like photoshop to draw a polygon through connecting dots.

The installation that I can use with Django is including the minified

```
<script src="/static/js/CanvasSpliner.min.js"></script>
```

then below it use it

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var cs = new CanvasSpliner("can", 300, 300);
    });
</script>
```

but this throws this error

```
color-editor:89 Uncaught TypeError: CanvasSpliner is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (color-editor:89)
    at k (jquery.js:15)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:15)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:15)
    at HTMLDocument.D (jquery.js:15)
```

if you click on the `color-editor:89` line from the HTML template it's this line from the above script

```
var cs = new CanvasSpliner("can", 300, 300);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `CanvasSpliner` with `CanvasSpliner.CanvasSpliner`

```
var cs = new CanvasSpliner.CanvasSpliner("can", 300, 300);
```

Found out this while playing around in chrome console.

The usage can also be found in the source code in its [demo](http://me.jonathanlurie.fr/canvasSpliner/). Maybe it is just a mistake in the readme.md.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jonathanlurie/canvasSpliner@master/dist/CanvasSpliner.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var cs = new CanvasSpliner.CanvasSpliner("can", 300, 300);
    });
</script>
```